# Javascript error in Apex while navigating the page to different url oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have grid column and that should get the page url and redirect to that page which i click that column name, but i am getting JS error and its not moving to another page from the URL the link taken as below

Js code in grid column

javascript:var x=window.open( '&DOCUMENT_URL.' ,  '_blank' )

Url which is taking automatically:

[https://devords.bluqube.co.uk/devmain1/atob('Zj9wPTIwMDoyNDAxOjgzMTM3NDc3NTUyMTk6QVBFWF9DTE9ORV9TRVNTSU9OOjoyNDAxOlAyNDAxX0RPQ1VNRU5UX0lELFAyNDAxX0xFREdFUl9UWVBFOjEzMTc2NzgsUyZjcz0zWXBWUGZKOVN6YzBZaENVX254aWRDTmRTcDFkaUhoaXkyYy16bjRFckNTX2ZySkx3dVlzLXhhZ0hFUUx6bUhkY3RPMmF5ZkE5SXoxdWFRNEItQTNnWUE=')](https://devords.bluqube.co.uk/devmain1/atob(%27Zj9wPTIwMDoyNDAxOjgzMTM3NDc3NTUyMTk6QVBFWF9DTE9ORV9TRVNTSU9OOjoyNDAxOlAyNDAxX0RPQ1VNRU5UX0lELFAyNDAxX0xFREdFUl9UWVBFOjEzMTc2NzgsUyZjcz0zWXBWUGZKOVN6YzBZaENVX254aWRDTmRTcDFkaUhoaXkyYy16bjRFckNTX2ZySkx3dVlzLXhhZ0hFUUx6bUhkY3RPMmF5ZkE5SXoxdWFRNEItQTNnWUE=%27))

Can anyone help

I am expecting the when i click the column name it has to redirect correclty , i have mentioned the url in grid select query for that column but why its taking the below link

[https://devords.bluqube.co.uk/devmain1/atob('Zj9wPTIwMDoyNDAxOjgzMTM3NDc3NTUyMTk6QVBFWF9DTE9ORV9TRVNTSU9OOjoyNDAxOlAyNDAxX0RPQ1VNRU5UX0lELFAyNDAxX0xFREdFUl9UWVBFOjEzMTc2NzgsUyZjcz0zWXBWUGZKOVN6YzBZaENVX254aWRDTmRTcDFkaUhoaXkyYy16bjRFckNTX2ZySkx3dVlzLXhhZ0hFUUx6bUhkY3RPMmF5ZkE5SXoxdWFRNEItQTNnWUE=')](https://devords.bluqube.co.uk/devmain1/atob(%27Zj9wPTIwMDoyNDAxOjgzMTM3NDc3NTUyMTk6QVBFWF9DTE9ORV9TRVNTSU9OOjoyNDAxOlAyNDAxX0RPQ1VNRU5UX0lELFAyNDAxX0xFREdFUl9UWVBFOjEzMTc2NzgsUyZjcz0zWXBWUGZKOVN6YzBZaENVX254aWRDTmRTcDFkaUhoaXkyYy16bjRFckNTX2ZySkx3dVlzLXhhZ0hFUUx6bUhkY3RPMmF5ZkE5SXoxdWFRNEItQTNnWUE=%27))

Comment: From the question it sounds like you're trying to do something in a sub optimal way. Rather than trying to fix the error you're getting now I'd try to do it "the APEX" way. What are you trying to achieve ? Please describe in as much detail as possible - it sounds you want a column in an interactive grid to link to another page. Is that correct ? Is it an apex page you're linking to ?

Comment: Also... you've tagged very old versions of apex and a very old version of the oracle db. Pls mention the version of APEX you're on.